# stuck on freecodecamp survey project

Tags: html

I'm currently working on the `freecodecamp` survey project and I'm stuck on step 15. I've put the code I entered below. But I get an error messages saying:

> You should add the first input after the label text 
> Enter Your First Name:, and include a space after the colon

this is the question:

> Nest an input element within each label. Be sure to add each input after the label text, and include a space after the colon.

here's my code:

```html
  <fieldset>
        <label>Enter Your First Name:
      <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
        </label>
        <label>Enter Your Last Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
        </label>
        <label>Enter Your Email:
     <input type="text" id="name" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </label>
        <label>Create a New Password:
    <input type="text" id="name" name="password" placeholder="Create a New Password">
        </label>
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: Please add the actual code and not an image of the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... Your solution looks fine to me.  We don't really know what that offsite resource is looking for.  Maybe it's examining whitespace more specifically than a browser does?  Maybe the wording of the question was mistaken?  Maybe something else?  But you have indeed nested an `<input>` within a `<label>` and included whitespace after the text.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Try to add input fields without any attributes. Seems like the question does not expect you to put all of that attributes. Try just a white space and a <input />

Answer (score -1):

im in step 19, my code looks something like this, try copy and

label for="first-name">Enter Your First Name: input id="first-name" type="text"

Enter Your First Name:

Comment: Hello, it appears that some code in your answer is unformatted/missing. Please use the editor to format your code, and also make sure that none is missing.